# Why does my TMC2208 only rotate my stepper motor in one direction?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, stepper-driver, tmc2208

I have two TMC2208 stepper drivers, both with the exact same problem. They both only allow the motor to rotate in one direction. They are currently used inside a CoreXY style 3D printer. In my case, both the Z motors have this problem. (For example, if I lower the build plate, the build plate lowers, but when I want to raise the build plate, the motors still make the build plate go down).

I have isolated this is a hardware problem by switching the defective motor drivers with my X and Y motor drivers, and after I did, the Z motors were able to raise and lower the build plate properly. However, the defective motor drivers seem to be able to turn the motors, so I don't understand where the problem originates from.

Possibly relevant details:

- I have been using Pronterface to control my 3D printer manually.
- Vrefs on my stepper drivers are set at X,Y,Z,Z2 on 0.9v, and E0 is on 1.1v
- My stepper motors are [these](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-17-bipolar-59ncm-84oz-in-2a-42x48mm-4-wires-w-1m-cable-and-connector.html)
- The TMC2208 are configured in StealthChop2 mode.

If there are any details I missed, please notify me.